# SQL login asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2016

I was thinking about login trough SQL
I created basic login form as shown below

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs="Data Source=Dev-PC;Initial Catalog=CodeSolution;User ID=sa; password=12345678"
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    con.Open();
    String sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE "+
                     "username = @user AND password = @pwd"
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", TextBox2.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Details.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please enter valid Username and Password')</script>");
    }
}
```

But then this got me thinking because without login people might guess the url of Details.aspx

So then i wondered what if the login was successful, to also add a column to the tblLogin and there store the sessionID of that user.
Then pages should only check if the sessionID equals that of tblLogin for that user.

I'm wondering 2 things here about this:

- How to store the session id into tblLogin as is known by the IIS server
- Is this a poormansolution, or would it be acceptable (with the drawback that each asp page should start with a function to check against valid session id).

*One error removed, the LIKE in sqlCommand its now =*

Comment: Assuming you're making a new project, you should definitely invest time to write a MVC project instead of a forms project. And you can solve this with routing and you don't need to store the session id anywhere, it's already a part of the request data I believe.

Comment: Have you used [ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)? There's a lot of standard concepts for authentication & authorization implemented there, which even if you choose to roll your own identity system, should hint what you're doing right and what you're doing wrong right now.

Comment: The solution is to check the Session in Master Page Load. **But note this is outdated form of login**. You shall use ASP.NET Identity

Comment: I've just dived into ASP.net, after understanding the basic SQL operations the thing, what i felt missing was a simple form of security; i thought lets build on futher on sessionID since thats unique per session. as autodidact i plan to read more about MVC later, my next topic will be Web Api and Rest Api

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be doing *so* many things wrong, that writing a proper answer would automatically make this question too broad. I'll give it a try:

- Don't hardcode connection strings. Store them in your configuration file and reference them by name.
- Don't use your `sa` account ever, not even for development.
- Don't prefix tables with `tbl`, it's redundant.
- Don't use `like` for usernames and passwords, you want an exact match.
- Don't store passwords in plaintext.
- *"people might guess the url of Details.aspx"* - you check authorization (*"is this user allowed to perform this action"*) on every action.

Explaining how to fix all these issues will require too much effort. Don't reinvent the wheel called authorization and authentication. Use a secure, tested, supported library for this.

You may want to look into [ASP.NET Membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) or its successor [ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity).

Comment: i do use a configuration file, but for this code example i included it cause it was simpler that way to explain what i was doing, personally i prefer tblName notation but your right about LIKE. I will dive later into other libraries for it. I was just wondering if this could work I think it can work.

Answer (score 0):

Not exact answer to your question, but this will be a good guide/advice.

Your idea of having a session ID is not bad at all (depending on requirement of your site/system).  But in this case not the session from the IIS because you need to decrypt it which will make you vulnerable to in-line attack (makes your DB/root folder accessible).

Here's the example on how to get session id of the session during the login but not from IIS (you can use this for logging):

`string sessionId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;`

And as per Database Design, better to have separate table for logging sessions of the user.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will gone make it just for the fun of it.
SessionID's in the end are what seperates user session so I thought why not use it that way as a check

Comment: Well SessionID is different to every session that a user log in.. but doesn't mean that when a different session is active other session (with same login) will expire, not unless you specify that to your code.

Comment: There are many ways on creating session for a user, you can even use the users ID from DB as its session, since session is a global variable